# How to get a formGroup valid after clearValidators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to remove a `Validators.required` in order to make a form valid. But whatever I do, none of that is happening

Here is my logic:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    type: new FormControl('test', [Validators.required]),
});

this.form.get('name').clearValidators();
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-44upaz?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Whatever I do, the `form.valid` is always false. Any suggestions why the `form.valid` property is not `true`?

Comment: You need to update the control, not the formgroup `this.form.get('name').updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: Yes thats it, you have to do both, on the control and group. Thnx!!

Comment: I don't think the one on the group is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call updateValueAndValidity on individual control

```
this.form.get('name').clearValidators();
this.form.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
```

**[Forked Working Example:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ambqfp?file=src/main.ts)**